# Error: endorsement failure during invoke in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, invoke, chaincode

When I try to invoke, it says:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:
"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction eeb54c350c04b037d457f10d085346d59111d1e49ef851860411191e0fe4c891: 
could not launch chaincode investments_1.0:3e64bf44ed94e792e48148741847895cb85ff0e05307b7fdfa17302ebe46
1b93: chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0"
```

Don't know what to do anymore. Can someone help me?

I'm using Hyperledger Fabric test-network to do a POC. I'm following all the steps at the docs, but I'm facing some problems with the chaincode invoke. I package a chaincode in node that I wrote, installed and approved in the two peers (`peer0.org1.example.com` and `peer0.org2.example.com`) and committed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The chaincode is launched in its own Docker container. The image for the chaincode will likely have some long name, similar to:

```
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-basic_1.0-e4de097efb5be42d96aebc4bde18eea848aad0f5453453ba2aad97f2e41e0d57-1ab8fa5c0161afbe94c6f8e185d0363a99e12755f088ca62deb25aa8f1aa4f1e
```

Your chaincode container - based on this chaincode image - has exited and so will not appear in the list of running containers. If you list all containers with `docker ps --all` then you should see it. You will need to use the [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command to view the container logs to see why it failed.

The peer logs might also hold some information about the failure from the peer end, since the peer communicates with the chaincode container to execute smart contract transaction functions.